# NTLDR is missing when trying to boot from USB drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

I've just followed [these instructions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jeffloucks/archive/2009/10/08/creating-usb-bootable-using-diskpart-and-using-it-to-install-windows-7.aspx) to make my USB HDD bootable, to install Server 2008 R2, but when I set my BIOS to boot from USB HDD, I get the error "NTLDR is missing".  I did copy all the Server 2008 R2 files over from the ISO after mounting the ISO.

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

NTLDR is Missing Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to reboot

I googled a while but I didn't get a straight and simple answer. Some one also had this issue and they were suggested to recreate the USB driver again, but this didn't fix the problem.

After a few research, I finally came up with a very simple solution:

1. Boot the existing Windows (my one is XP, but Windows 7 should also
   work).
2. Insert the created Windows 7/8 installer USB drive.
3. Open a command window, go to the USB drive (my one is `G:`). Change directory to `USBDRIVE:\boot` (for example, `cd G:\boot`). This directory contains the executable file `bootsect.exe`. Under this directory, run the following command:

   `bootsect /nt60 USBDRIVE:`

Answer (score 1):

If NTLDR is Missing, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to reboot.
I got the same error message, but it was caused by different factors.

My BIOS setting was "legacy" and my USB driver was GPT.
After I updated the BIOS setting to UEFI, it fixed the error.